# Adding UIWebView to UIViewController gives me a white screen. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I have a button press function that is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
  NSLog(@"Loading WebView controller...");
  [self loadUIWebView];
}
```

The button press function calls the following function, which should load a full screen UIWebView on top of my UIViewContoller (the class where I am calling this is an instance of UIViewController).

```
- (void)loadUIWebView
{
  NSString* currentURL = @"http://www.google.com";
  NSLog(@"Attempting to load %@", currentURL);
  UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];   
  [webView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];
  [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentURL]]];
  [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

However, no matter what the URL, my app goes to a white screen. As you can see in the loadUIWebView function, I am trying to set the background color of the UIWebView to red in order to see whether it's being displayed - the background is white so I am guessing it's a problem with the way the UIWebView is presented.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try loading the request after adding the web view to the parent view. Also, set the view controller's view's background color to some color other than white to see if it appears.

Comment: What's your application flow? I'm asking because the code you posted should work..

Comment: Good call Maddy. I am doing this but it did not work [webView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];

Comment: I'm not sure what an application flow is but the app is really simple. I have a single UIViewController that I start off in and I'm trying to load a WebView on top of it.

Comment: @KonstantinGizdarski You missed my point. Make the view controller's view have a green background in addition to the web view's red background. Now, do you see green, white, or red?

Comment: @maddy got it. I added [self.view setBackgroundColor: [UIColor greenColor]]; After pressing the button, I still see a blank white screen.

Comment: The white background should be from the web view indicating it's there but showing a blank page for some reason. Did you try moving the call to `loadRequest` to after the call to `addSubview:`?

Comment: You should implement the delegate methods so you can see if it is loading, succeeded or failed. Also move the load request to the end as suggested by @rmaddy.

Comment: I ran the app on a simulator and the UIWebView worked. I think the problem is with my phone's network connection. It doesn't seem to want to make outgoing network requests (except to a VM I spun up behind a firewall ?_?). I think I'll take it from here, though. Thanks again! @rmaddy -- you were right. The web view did load properly.

Comment: Try to set the tint color also .!

Answer (score 1):

Setting `backgroundColor` on a `UIWebView` won't show. I'd recommend hiding the web view until it's content is loaded, using whatever placeholder you want, then when the page finishes show the web view. You can see when a web view finishes loading via the `-webViewDidFinishLoad:` delegate method.

Comment: The WebView was pointing to a page on the company intranet. However, I was connected to the public Wi-Fi network.

Your suggestion was helpful as following it showed me that the WebView never loads.